# Can I only Render light that psses through an object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, shaders, lighting

In the image below I would like only the light that passes through the sphere, in this case the bright dot in the center, to be visible. Is there a way to set this up in cycles?

[image]

Thanks,
Tyler

Comment: The bright light in your image is caused by Caustics but unfortunately there is no easy way (that I'm aware of) to render just the caustics from the image - and they are switched on/off via the Render properties so are not configurable via Scene or Render Layer. The only method I know that would allow you to do this would be to render the image once with Caustics enabled and again with Caustics disabled - then use the compositor to subtract the non-caustic image from the one with caustics, resulting in just the caustics left behind. If this sounds like a viable solution I can write an answer.

Comment: For caustics you would be better off not using cycles, but luxrender.

Comment: Or you can try Yafaray

Answer (score 1):

See this .blend file. I used nodes with the Transmission Depth node and two emission shaders joined with a mix shader. Set the green one to 0 strength and it should have the desired effect. I'll post a screen shot of the node set up in a moment. (The node set up for the lamp. It's a point source directly above the glass sphere.)

Here is the node set up.
[image: node set up]
The green is what will go away. The pink it what will be rendered.
[image: green enabled]
Green disabled (strength is set to 0).
[image: green disabled]
[image]